# unable to initialize Static const string

Tags: c++

I have a class "GameOverState" which has a private member

`static const std::string s_gameOverID;`

In GameOverState.cpp I am initialising as :

```
const std::string GameOverState::s_gameOverID = "GAMEOVER";
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [9]' to 'int' 
error C2377: 'std::string' : redefinition; typedef cannot be overloaded with any other symbol
error C2373: 's_gameOverID' : redefinition; different type modifiers    
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'GameOverState::s_gameOverID'
```

I have a PlayState class/PauseState class which have the same implementation which are working fine. How do I fix this bug??

GameOverState.h

```
#pragma once

#include "GameState.h"
#include "PlayState.h"
#include "MenuState.h"
#include "PauseState.h"
#include "AnimatedGraphic.h"
#include <string>


class GameObject;

class GameOverState : public GameState
{
public:
  virtual void update();
  virtual void render();
  virtual bool onEnter();
  virtual bool onExit();
  virtual std::string getStateID() const { return s_gameOverID; }
private:
  static void s_gameOverToMain();
  static void s_restartPlay();
  static const std::string s_gameOverID;
  std::vector<GameObject*> m_gameObjects;
}
```

GameOverState.cpp
       #include "GameOverState.h"

```
const std::string GameOverState::s_gameOverID = "GAMEOVER";

void GameOverState::s_gameOverToMain()
{
  TheGame::Instance()->getStateMachine()->changeState(new MenuState());
}

void GameOverState::s_restartPlay()
{
  TheGame::Instance()->getStateMachine()->changeState(new PlayState());
}

bool GameOverState::onEnter()
{
  if (!TheTextureManager::Instance()->load("assets/gameover.png", "gameovertext", TheGame::Instance()->getRenderer()))
  {
    return false;
  }
  if (!TheTextureManager::Instance()->load("assets/main.png", "mainbutton", TheGame::Instance()->getRenderer()))
  {
    return false;
  }
  if (!TheTextureManager::Instance()->load("assets/restart.png", "restartbutton", TheGame::Instance()->getRenderer()))
  {
    return false;
  }
  GameObject* gameOverText = new AnimatedGraphic(new LoaderParams(200, 100, 190, 30, "gameovertext"), 2);
  GameObject* button1 = new MenuButton(new LoaderParams(200, 200, 200, 80, "mainbutton"), s_gameOverToMain);
  GameObject* button2 = new MenuButton(new LoaderParams(200, 300, 200, 80, "restartbutton"), s_restartPlay);
  m_gameObjects.push_back(gameOverText);
  m_gameObjects.push_back(button1);
  m_gameObjects.push_back(button2);
  std::cout << "entering PauseState\n";
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Do you have `#include <string>` in this .cpp?

Comment: Are you missing `#include <string>` before your class declaration?

Comment: Show a bit more code.

Comment: How does the header look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the semicolon after the definition of `GameOverState`.

The preprocessor runs before compilation and basically just copy pastes the content of the header in the source file, altough we can't see that. An error resulting from a broken header can thus be pretty misleading.

It's legal to have class definitions inside a variable definition and the position of specifiers (like `static`) is not limited to the beginning of a declaration, either (for example, `int const static x = 0;` is fine).

So, your code looks like this to the compiler:

```
class GameOverState {} static const std::string GameOverState::s_gameOverID = "GAMEOVER";
```

Hopefully the errors make more sense now.

Comment: Thank you! can't believe I missed that. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else has said, you're probably missing the #include line in your header if your other two classes are working fine. It's presuming and expecting an int, so that seems the case.

Make sure `#include<string>` is in your header

Comment: Just pasted the code.I have included string header.Still having the same problem.

Comment: I don;t think it should be const for now, try removing that because it could be causing some issues